# Using ZMQ within Cython

Tags: python, cython, zeromq, pyzmq

I've gotten ZMQ to work in .py files but I want to use it in a cython class but have not figure out how to import the right library in to .pyx files. Example:

```
import zmq
from zmq.backend.cython.socket cimport Socket
from zmq.backend.cython.context import Context

cdef class MyClass:

    cdef public str tick_port
    cdef public Socket socket
    cdef public Context context

    def __cinit__(self,tick_port):

        self.tick_port = tick_port

        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        self.socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")  # Note.

    
    def StartData(self):
        ''' market data comes in here '''
        self.socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:" + str(self.tick_port))
        while True:
            tick_message = self.socket.recv_json()
            print("Data: " + str(tick_message))
            #self.OnTick(eval(tick_message))
```

how do you correctly declare and define various zmq variables within cython? so I still create `context` and `socket` objects like in python? Lots of newbie question but I couldn't find anything from googling "how to use zmq in cython".

for example when compiling the above I get error:

`C attribute of type '<error>' cannot be accessed from pythong.`

Thanks,

Comment: It should be probably `cimport` in `from zmq.backend.cython.context import Context`. Also having a real minimal [mre] and a full error message  would make the question clearer.

Comment: There's probably little to be gained from this: it looks to me like they mainly use Cython to create a Python interface. I doubt if there's much advantage to using it from Cython rather than Python. You can always type things as `object` in Cython

Comment: ahh didn't know about the `object` variable. thats solves my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Things to note:

1. As mentioned in comments by user DavidW, it appears the Cython code utilizes Python objects & therefore using the Cython module directly from Cython doesn't benefit from possible speedups & releasing the GIL, etc. So just using `cdef object context = zmq.Context()` and `cdef object socket = context.Socket(...)` (etc.) is a fine way to go. If you wanted to speed things up or achieve total releasing of the Python GIL within a function, you might need to wrap/call the CZMQ or libzmq libraries from your own Cython code.
2. You can still do what you were trying to do above & use the Cython types from Cython code. However:

   - As mentioned by user ead in comments, you have to `cimport` `Context` similar to how you `cimport`-ed `Socket`
   - The Socket and Context types within `zmq.backend.cython` have different interfaces from the high-level `zmq.Socket` and `zmq.Context` classes. You will have to look at the code in the corresponding .pyx files for full details, but for the example above:

     - The Cython `Context` class has no `socket` method. You have to instantiate a `Socket` manually, and the first argument is `context=...`, which you will use to specify the `Context` you instantiated prior.
     - The Cython `Socket` class has no `setsockopt` method, but does have an equivalent `set` method.
     - The Cython `Socket` class has no `recv_json` method, so you will have to use `recv` and then convert the returned value to JSON using another library.

See files `context.pyx` and `socket.pyx` in the codebase here: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/tree/main/zmq/backend/cython

A corrected version of your code follows:

```py
import zmq
from zmq.backend.cython.socket cimport Socket
from zmq.backend.cython.context cimport Context

cdef class MyClass:

    cdef public str tick_port
    cdef public Socket socket
    cdef public Context context

    def __cinit__(self,tick_port):

        self.tick_port = tick_port

        self.context = Context()
        self.socket = Socket(self.context, zmq.SUB)
        self.socket.set(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")  # Note.

    
    def StartData(self):
        ''' market data comes in here '''
        self.socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:" + str(self.tick_port))
        while True:
            tick_message = self.socket.recv()
            print("Data: " + str(tick_message))
            #self.OnTick(eval(tick_message))
```